# WCF IOutboundHandler Send non xml

Tags: wcf

I am trying to write a custom WCF Adapter using the WCF LOB Adapter SDK.  Everything seems to work ok, except that I need to send a text string to the downstream system over a socket.  When the Execute Method of the IOutboundhandler gets exectued I get the following error:

`System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

With the following stack trace:

```
  at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)".
```

Here is my execute Method:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Executes the request message on the target system and returns a response message.
    /// If there isn’t a response, this method should return null
    /// </summary>

    public Message Execute(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        OperationMetadata om = this.MetadataLookup.
                        GetOperationDefinitionFromOutputMessageAction(message.Headers.Action, timeout);

        if (om == null)
        {
            throw new AdapterException("Invalid operation " + message.Headers.Action);
        }

        MessageBuffer msgBuffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);

        XmlDictionaryReader reader = msgBuffer.CreateMessage().GetReaderAtBodyContents();

        XmlDocument request = new XmlDocument();
        request.LoadXml(reader.ReadOuterXml());

        string positionalRs = this.Connection.Send(request.OuterXml);

        XmlDocument response = new XmlDocument();
        response.LoadXml(positionalRs);

        XmlReader replyReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response.InnerXml));
        return Message.CreateMessage(message.Version, message.Headers.Action + "/Response", replyReader);
    }
```

How can I access the body of a WCF message that is not xml?

here is what my WCF Message looks like:

Message:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:a=http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing
xmlns:s=http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope> 
<s:Header> 
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand=1>TCPCall</a:Action> 
<a:MessageID>urn:uuid:e473f4e4-f6f5-47b5-92a6-123116fafaa5</a:MessageID> 
<a:ReplyTo> 
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address> 
 </a:ReplyTo> 
</s:Header> 
<s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body> 
</s:Envelope>
```

the body of the message is not xml. whenever I try and acess it I get the following error:

`"System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

I am trying to send data at a socket on the other end using wfc. I seem to have everything working, except the ability to pull out the contents of the WCF message if they are not xml.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be using the wrong WCF binding for your project. The basicHttp, wsHttp, & netTcp bindings all assume you are dealing with soap (xml) documents. Sounds like you may want to look at the webHttpBinding and/or the various WCF REST toolkits which give more options for building you request & response documents (XML or json but don't know about plain text). More detail about what you are trying to do would be helpful in getting better answers.